# How does Raku decide which version of a module gets loaded?

Tags: module, package, versioning, raku, api-versioning

When I do `use Foo:ver<1.0>;` it loads version 1.0 of module `Foo`. But what happens when I do `use Foo;`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR: When given no specific version a default Raku install will load the latest version from the first `CompUnit::Repository` it encounters that matches any version of that module (and not neccesarily the highest version out of all `CompUnit::Repository`).

---

It is possible to create and load a non-core `CompUnit::Repository` that itself would only load random versions of a module unless otherwise specified. This answer does not apply to these and will focus on how the various core `CompUnit::Repository` behave and is specced.

The first thing that determines what module will be loaded is which `CompUnit::Repository` matches the requested identity first. The default repository chain will look something like this:

```
# EXAMPLE 1

$ raku -e '.say for $*REPO.repo-chain'
inst#/home/ugexe/.raku
inst#/home/ugexe/raku/install/share/perl6/site
inst#/home/ugexe/raku/install/share/perl6/vendor
inst#/home/ugexe/raku/install/share/perl6
```

The `inst#` prefix tells us this is a `CompUnit::Repository::Installation`. This is relevant because such a repo can contain multiple distributions -- including multiple versions of the same distribution -- which is not true of the single-distribution `CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem` used for `-I.` or `-Ilib` (which are *really* `-Ifile#/home/ugexe/repos/Foo` and `-Ifile#/home/ugexe/repos/Foo/lib`).

```
# EXAMPLE 2

$ raku -I. -e '.say for $*REPO.repo-chain'
file#/home/ugexe/repos/Foo
inst#/home/ugexe/.raku
inst#/home/ugexe/raku/install/share/perl6/site
inst#/home/ugexe/raku/install/share/perl6/vendor
inst#/home/ugexe/raku/install/share/perl6
```

Lets assume the following:

- `file#/home/ugexe/repos/Foo` contains `Foo:ver<0.5>`
- `inst#/home/ugexe/.raku` contains `Foo:ver<0.1>` and `Foo:ver<1.0>`
- `inst#/home/ugexe/.raku` contains `Foo:ver<2.0>` and `Foo:ver<0.1>`

`use Foo;` will load:

- **EXAMPLE 1** - `Foo:ver<1.0>` from `inst#/home/ugexe/.raku`
- **EXAMPLE 2** - `Foo:ver<0.5>` from `file#/home/ugexe/repos/Foo`

Even though the highest version out of all the repositories is `Foo:ver<2.0>` the first repository in the chain that matches *any* version of Foo (i.e. `use Foo`) wins, so `Foo:ver<2.0>` is never chosen. You might guess this makes "highest version" the second thing that determines which version of a module gets loaded, but its really the 4th! However I've mentioned it here because for typical usage this is sufficient enough.

---

The 2nd thing that determines which version of a module get loaded is the `api` field. This essentially is another version field that, when combined with the version itself, gives a basic way of pinning major versions.

Lets assume the following:

- `file#/home/ugexe/repos/Foo` contains `Foo:api<0>:ver<0.5>`
- `inst#/home/ugexe/.raku` contains `Foo:api<1>:ver<0.1>` and `Foo:api<0>:ver<1.0>`

`use Foo;` will load:

- **EXAMPLE 1** - `Foo:api<1>:ver<0.1>` from `inst#/home/ugexe/.raku`
- **EXAMPLE 2** - `Foo:api<0>:ver<0.5>` from `file#/home/ugexe/repos/Foo`

Even though in EXAMPLE 1 the highest version is `Foo:api<0>:ver<1.0>`, the highest api version is `Foo:api<1>:ver<0.1>` and thus is chosen.

---

The 3rd thing that determines which version of a module gets loaded is the `auth` field. Unlike `api` and `ver` it does not imply any sorting. And also unlike `api` and `ver` field you probably shouldn't be using it in your e.g. `use Foo` -- it is policy focused and will serve to be a power-tool/escape hatch most developers should hopefully never have to worry about (ab)using.

Lets assume the following:

- `file#/home/ugexe/repos/Foo` contains `Foo:auth<github:ugexe>:ver<0.5>`
- `inst#/home/ugexe/.raku` contains `Foo:ver<0.1>` and `Foo:auth<github:ugexe>:ver<1.0>`

`use Foo;` will load:

- **EXAMPLE 1** - `Foo:auth<github:ugexe>:ver<1.0>` from `inst#/home/ugexe/.raku`
- **EXAMPLE 2** - `Foo:auth<github:ugexe>:ver<0.5>` from `file#/home/ugexe/repos/Foo`

In both examples `use Foo;` is the same as `use Foo:auth(*):ver(*)`, so even though one of the repo assumptions contains a module with no `auth` this does not mean it is an exact match for `use Foo;`. Instead the `:auth(*)` includes any `auth` value as a match (effectively meaning `auth` is ignored altogether).

---

For more examples the [spec tests](https://github.com/Raku/roast/blob/4ec7d433a47ee7344316959db9a0a6cdf90a918d/S11-repository/cur-candidates.t) are a good source

Comment: Thumbs up for these nice SO Q/A pairs. Are you planning/hoping to post another pair covering `auth` in the next few weeks? In case not, am I right when I assume that a `use` statement with*out* an `auth` field *always* ignores the `auth` metainfo? (I'm assuming this due to what would be logical to me; and one interpretation of what you've written; and the lines in the test file with `.candidates($cuspec-any-auth).elems` and `.installed.grep(*.defined).elems` in them; and your decision not to explain this further in this SO because it's "outside the scope of this post".) TIA for a reply.

Comment: @raiph that is correct, and I added an example for `auth`. What I was trying to avoid is explaining how `auth` is intended to be used. It is more policy focused and will serve to be a power-tool/escape hatch most developers should hopefully never have to worry about (ab)using.

Comment: "you probably shouldn't be using [auth] in your e.g. use Foo" Is this still correct/best practice?  My understanding is that `auth` is very important to prevent loading a package uploaded by a different (possibly malicious) person. See https://github.com/Raku/problem-solving/issues/340#issuecomment-1205401266. Is that incorrect?

Comment: It sort of depends. If you are only consuming modules from a trusedt source then the malicious aspect could be ignored. In that scenario one can then start using `auth` to provide an alternative implementation of something (perhaps some patched variant a company needs a different dependency to use). If the `auth` is hard coded then they can't do that. `emulates` or `supercedes` could likely provide similar functionality though